# How to create Cross dissolve and Rack focus effects in Cocoa touch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, animation

I want to use cross dissolve and rack focus animation in my app.
So, just wanted to know that how can we create custom animations.

To understand Rack focus, here is a youtube link :http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzC0Ek6X5FY

By Rack focus , I want to show 2 views in this effect.Firstly, the background view should be crisp & clear & the top or foreground should be blurred. Then slowly, the background view should become blurred & the foreground crisp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For  cross dissolve tried this

```
[UIView beginAnimations: @"cross dissovle" context: NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.0f];
self.firstView.alpha = 0.0f;
self.secondView.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

not really sure what you mean by rack focus animation

Comment: accepted for cross dissolve till the time I am not getting any answer for rack focus.